# Control name of built-in generic parameter in WCF DataContract

Tags: wcf, wsdl, asmx, datacontract

I am converting asmx web service to wcf while attempting to maintain backwards compatibility in the WSDL. One of the DataContract classes is generic. When the generic parameter is a built-in type, such as bool, the first letter is lowercased in WCF, whereas it was uppercased in asmx. E.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class MethodResult<T>
{
}
```

would generate

```
MethodResultOfBoolean
```

in asmx.

```
[DataContract(Name="MethodResultOf{0}")]
public class MethodResult<T>
{
}
```

generates

```
MethodResultOfboolean
```

in WCF.

Is there a way to make it use an uppercase letter in WCF?

Comment: It is not just casing, MethodResultOfInt32 in asmx is MethodResultOfint in WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding `[XmlSerializerFormatAttribute]` to the ServiceContract interface fixed this.